# How to enable Unity Launcher on startup?

Tags: gnome, launcher, startup, unity-dash, unity-2d

My Ubuntu 12.04 LTS laptop has the Unity 2D along with the classic GNOME interface but it wouldn't launch automatically on startup, Only after I type 'unity' on the terminal the Unity 2D Launcher as well as the Dash board starts launching. How do I make the Unity Launcher show on startup itself without opening the terminal and typing 'unity'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand well, your computer launch gnome automatically and you want it to launch unity? So on your login screen, you should see a little circle on the right of your pseudo, click on it and just choose Unity 2D.

Comment: Happy that it helped you, don't forget to mark the question as solved and good luck with Ubuntu

Comment: Thank you so much brother! Actually I'm a newbie at Ubuntu, so don't have much idea on stuff. Thank you so much!